# configure congnito refresh token expiration time

Tags: amazon-cognito

In my app, I make a call to getSession if the user refreshes the page or tries to access a client side rout that requires the user to be authenticated.

The problem I am seeing is that the refreshToken never expires.

So I do this:

```
const currentSession = await authorisationProvider.getSession();

this.setState({ isAuthenticated: currentSession && currentSession.isValid(), busy: false });
```

But having stepped through the code and if the cachedSession.isValid() call returns false then a call is made to refreshToken which always appears to return new tokens no matter how long I leave it.

Does the refreshToken never expire or can I configure it to expire in an hour or so?

The only way for things to expire is for localStorage.clear() to be called which is obviously not a real solution.

Answer (score 3):

In aws Cognito console under General settings -> App clients tab you can configure refresh token expiration in days with limit  1-3650 days

Reference: [Refresh Token expiration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-refresh-token)